# iOS IAP not working on Unity, "Service Unavailable"

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to test IAP of my game in Unity 3D but it doesn't work, it woks fine on Android but when I test it on iOS it said: Service Unavailable, please check your internet connection.
This is the log:

```
AdMob client has been initialized.
EasyMobile.AdClientImpl:Init()
EasyMobile.Advertising:SetupAdClient(AdNetwork)
EasyMobile.Advertising:get_AdMobClient()
EasyMobile.Advertising:GetWorkableAdClient(AdNetwork)
EasyMobile.Advertising:get_DefaultBannerAdClient()
EasyMobile.Advertising:ShowBannerAd(BannerAdPosition)

(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)

2019-02-20 14:39:02.410174+0100 tapsky[6450:2398639] <Google> To get test ads on this device, set: request.testDevices = @[ @"3de524b688608295a3dbf784dd31f9aa" ];
Creating new default banner...
EasyMobile.AdMobClientImpl:InternalShowBannerAd(AdPlacement, BannerAdPosition, BannerAdSize)
EasyMobile.AdClientImpl:ShowBannerAd(AdPlacement, BannerAdPosition, BannerAdSize)
EasyMobile.Advertising:ShowBannerAd(IAdClient, AdPlacement, BannerAdPosition, BannerAdSize)

(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)

UnityAds client has been initialized.
EasyMobile.AdClientImpl:Init()
EasyMobile.Advertising:SetupAdClient(AdNetwork)
EasyMobile.Advertising:get_UnityAdsClient()
EasyMobile.Advertising:GetWorkableAdClient(AdNetwork)
EasyMobile.Advertising:GetAvailableNetworks()
EasyMobile.<CRAutoLoadAllAds>c__Iterator1:MoveNext()
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)

(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)

Please initialize the UnityAds client first.
EasyMobile.AdClientImpl:CheckInitialize(Boolean)
EasyMobile.AdClientImpl:LoadInterstitialAd(AdPlacement)
EasyMobile.Advertising:LoadAllInterstitialAds(List`1)
EasyMobile.<CRAutoLoadAllAds>c__Iterator1:MoveNext()
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)


(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)

UnityIAP Version: 1.20.1
UnityEngine.Purchasing.StandardPurchasingModule:Instance(AppStore)
EasyMobile.InAppPurchasing:InitializePurchasing()



(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)

Unavailable product com.yougamestudios.tapsky.10000c -com.yougamestudios.tapsky.10000c
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:CheckForInitialization()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:OnProductsRetrieved(List`1)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.AppleStoreImpl:OnProductsRetrieved(String)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Extension.UnityUtil:Update()

(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)

Unavailable product com.yougamestudios.tapsky.500c -com.yougamestudios.tapsky.500c
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:CheckForInitialization()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:OnProductsRetrieved(List`1)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.AppleStoreImpl:OnProductsRetrieved(String)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Extension.UnityUtil:Update()

(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)

In-App Purchasing OnInitializeFailed. InitializationFailureReason:NoProductsAvailable
```

I add the products to App Store but it still in review, can it be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of your log says:

> InitializationFailureReason:NoProductsAvailable

So yeah, I think you guessed right: while the products are in review you would not get them in the app.

Comment: Thank you!! I will wait to finish review